# Become Windows 10 search compliant with the fuzzy matching?

Tags: windows-10, findstr

Fuzzy matching allows some mistakes like inversion of two letter when you are searching a string.

For sample, you want to find the files that contains the string: "Albert Einstein". The "fuzzy matching" compliance allows to find these file even if you type "Alebrt Eisntein" by error.

How would I make Windows 10 search compliant with the fuzzy matching?

Comment: Windows 10 already does this. Type "sttings" into your search and Windows will suggest "Settings" correctly.

Comment: Answer and I will vote you and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 already performs "fuzzy" searching.

Evidence: Open Windows 10 search, type "sttings" and Windows will find the Settings app.